# How to apply the attribute "rel=nofollow" to links in the comments?

Tags: 7, comments

I configured the Text Format "Plain text" (admin/config/content/formats) to "Convert URLs into links" so I would like to add the attribute `rel="nofollow"` to all the links in the comments.

This way I would minimize the effects of spammy links in the comments.

Is there an easier way than using regular expressions to insert the attribute?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to *Configuration -> Content authoring -> Text formats -> Plain text (your format)*, then tick the `Limit allowed HTML tags` option.

In the filter settings at the bottom of the page is the `Add rel="nofollow" to all links` checkbox. Tick that... Since this is plain text, you will probably want to remove the contents of the `Allowed HTML Tags` field, too.

Comment: Oh my... that was easy. I should have seen that.

Comment: It's not in the most intuitive of places, I must say...

Comment: very cool! I wasted about half an hour too looking at extlink and links_nofollow modules ;-)

Comment: It does not work but this one does: http://befused.com/drupal/nofollow . Unfortunately it adds nofollow to internal links too. Here is alternate way: http://www.thecarneyeffect.co.uk/add-rel-nofollow-external-links-and-not-internal-links-drupal . Here is more about using nofollow with internal links: http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-nofollow-attributes-on-internal-links-dont-hurt-but-dont-do-it-173128

Answer (score 1):

Jim is mostly Right (but it matters what order the filters are in and you would need to add the `<a>` at least to that filter). A slightly better way (in that it lets users still put in just the URL or protects you if they try to all a rel=follow to their a tag) would be:

1. Go to `admin/config/content/formats/plain_text`
2. Check only `Limit allowed HTML tags`, `Convert line breaks...`, and `Convert URLs into links`.
3. Make sure your filter is ordered starting with `Convert URLs into links`, then `Limit allowed HTML tags`, then `Convert line breaks into HTML...`
4. Under Limit allowed HTML Tags filter settings, change allowed HTML to just `<a>` and make sure the Add `rel="no-follow"` to all links is checked. I like to unchecked the Display basic HTML help in long filter tips here.

Answer (score 0):

[noindex_external_links](https://drupal.org/project/noindex_external_links) is a nice module to add rel=nofollow to external sites. We can dofollow selected sites and it does not add nofollow to internal links.

To make it work I placed the filters in this order(for plain text format): Display any HTML as plain text -> Content URL's into links -> Noindex external links filter

Answer (score 0):

You can also use - https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_nofollow module, which provide an widget, which can be used to add rel="nofollow".